# using ajaxComplete on a non-ajax page?

Tags: jquery

Greetings to all,

I use ajaxComplete of jQuery to make sure all the ajax calls are finished before executing my functions. It works well if there are ajax calls before. However if there is no ajax calls on the page, my own functions don't get executed.

My question is how to do the following?

1) if there are ajax calls on the page, use ajaxComplete to make sure all the content is loaded first.

2) if there are no ajax calls, the functions are still executed.

Can someone shed some light on this issue? Any help would be appreciated,

Michael

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure that all the content is loaded first, you can use use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... })
```